# Failed using ProgressDialog in extends Fragment

Tags: java, android, progressdialog

Can someone tell me what wrong with my code ?
I want to call the ProgressDialog during loading the subject details.

Here is part of the whole code.

```
public class ScheduleFragment extends Fragment {
/*    others activity    */

public ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Loading subject in Background Thread
    new LoadAllSubject(getActivity()).execute();


class LoadAllSubject extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ScheduleFragment.this, "Progress", "Loading subjects. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call your background thread inside "onCreateView"

Comment: did u mean i need to create a new class ?

Comment: no, the fragment class has a method called onCreateView

Comment: but the ProgressDialog.show(ScheduleFragment.this, "Progress", "Loading subjects. Please wait..."); still have an error on .show(....)

Comment: oh, I understand now, I think you should use ScheduleFragment.this.getActivity()

Comment: thank you so much for your concern. 
Did u familiar with ListAdapter in Fragment ? I have certain issues on that

Comment: yeah I'm familiar with Adapters, but I think you should create other question for others to help too.

Comment: This is my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22617933/failed-using-listadapter-in-extends-fragment/22617974?noredirect=1#comment34441615_22617974). Glad if u could help me. Please master.